# Managing Privay : Sync outlook accounts based on connection type

Tags: windows, networking, email, microsoft-outlook, imap

My office monitors my inbound IMAP email address.

I have two accounts configured in my outlook, one is personal and other one is official. My outlook polls my email accounts every 5 minutes.

I want that my office email account should sync in any connection type and my personal email account should only sync when I am connected using my mobile internet connection. Both accounts are hosted on google mail.

Is such a configuration possible?